# PHP Random Image Function sometimes inserts blank image

Tags: php, html, wordpress, image

I have a function which opens a pre-designated directory, makes an array of the image files within the directory, then pulls a random image name from the array list to echo to a webpage. The problem is sometimes it doesn't actually pull the image name.

Here's the php code:

```
<?php

    $actualpath = get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . "/img/banners/";

    // open this directory 
    $myDirectory = opendir("wp-content/themes/beautysalon/img/banners/");

    // get each entry
    while($entryName = readdir($myDirectory)) {
        $dirArray[] = $entryName;
    }

    // close directory
    closedir($myDirectory);


    function getRandomFromArray($ar) {
        mt_srand( (double)microtime() * 1000000 ); // php 4.2+ not needed
        $num = array_rand($ar);
        return $ar[$num];
    }
    $randomPicture = getRandomFromArray($dirArray);

?>
```

And the code I use to actually display the image on the webpage:

```
<?php
    if ( !is_front_page() ) {
        echo '<img src="' . $actualpath . $randomPicture . '"/>';
    };

?>
```

When the code works it ends up echoing something like:

```
<src="http://sitename.com/directorypath/image.png" />
```

Which is exactly what I intend it to do. But when it doesn't work, it's not pulling the image name for some reason and ends up outputting something like this, which results in a broken image:

```
<src="http://sitename.com/directorypath/" />
```

It's almost as if the php hasn't had time to run through the function before the page content is generated, but I thought php always executed completely before the page was rendered.

[Working example of the PHP script in action can be found here.](http://garthmedia.com/beautysalon/sample-page/)

The script runs on all pages except the home page and the contact page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using **scandir** instead of **opendir**. Tell me if it works, if it doesn't I'll fix the code up. I've tested it on my side and it works.

```
<?php
// Your variables...
$actualpath = get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . "/img/banners/";
$directory = 'wp-content/themes/beautysalon/img/banners/';

// Scan the directory and strip the dots that come with the array
$sd = array_diff(scandir($directory), array('..', '.'));

// Sort the array so that the numbering is correct
sort($sd);

// The random array function.
function getRandomFromArray($ar) {
    return $ar[array_rand($ar)];
}

// Your variable.
$randomPicture = getRandomFromArray($sd);

?>
```

Good luck!

Comment: That seems to work perfectly. Any idea why the opendir method was creating issues?

Comment: I don't exactly know for sure, but it could be a problem with the PHP software itself. Please mark my answer as solved if it solved your problem. Thanks!

Comment: Marked as solved now. I was just waiting for your response before marking it as solved. I wanted your input on what may cause the issue and wasn't sure if you would come back if it was marked as solve. ;)

Comment: I'm glad it worked for you. Thanks a lot, but I'm not that kind of person. Good luck in doing whatever you're doing :)